# Java Swing components not showing

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, flowlayout

Help me! Whenever I try to start up the code below, it shows only the button on the bottom and the password field everywhere else. I want to be able to see everything, but I can't

```
public void setup(){
    frame = new JFrame("Votinator 3000");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    voteconfirm = new JLabel("");
    textarea = new JTextField(1);
    submit = new JButton("Submit Vote!");
    chooser = new JList(items);
    password = new JPasswordField(1);
    password.setVisible(true);
    choices = new JComboBox();
    choices.addItem("Choose");
    choices.addItem("Submit Own");
    type = new JPanel();
    type.add(textarea);
    choices.setEditable(false);
    choices.setSelectedIndex(0);
    frame.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 400);
    frame.getContentPane().add(type);
    frame.getContentPane().add(choices);
    frame.getContentPane().add(voteconfirm);
    frame.getContentPane().add(chooser);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textarea);
    frame.getContentPane().add(password,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(submit,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
frame.getContentPane().add(password,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Will replace anything else you've added to your screen...

This, will add the button to the bottom of the screen...

```
frame.getContentPane().add(submit,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

You could change the layout to a `FlowLayout`, that will display everything...

[image]

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 400);
frame.getContentPane().add(type);
frame.getContentPane().add(choices);
frame.getContentPane().add(voteconfirm);
frame.getContentPane().add(chooser);
frame.getContentPane().add(textarea);
frame.getContentPane().add(password);
frame.getContentPane().add(submit);
```

But I hardly think that's what you really want.

Take a read through

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

And see if you can find one or more layouts that suit your requirements

Answer (score 5):

`BorderLayout` is a default layout for `JFrame`. All the components in your code are added to `BorderLayout.CENTER` when there is no argument in `add()` method. So only `password` appears in `BorderLayout.CENTER` as it replaces other components. Try to create a panel, populate it with controls and add this panel to the frame, ie:

```
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.add(type);
content.add(choices);
content.add(voteconfirm);
content.add(chooser);
content.add(textarea);
content.add(password);
content.add(submit);
frame.getContentPane().add(content);
```

Here how it looks like:

[image]

EDIT:

From [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) spec:

> As a convenience, BorderLayout interprets the absence of a string
>   specification the same as the constant CENTER:
>
> ```
> Panel p2 = new Panel();
> p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
> p2.add(new TextArea());  // Same as p.add(new TextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This is quick fix:

```
public void setup(){
frame = new JFrame("Votinator 3000");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
voteconfirm = new JLabel("");
textarea = new JTextField(1);
submit = new JButton("Submit Vote!");
chooser = new JList(items);
password = new JPasswordField(1);
password.setVisible(true);
choices = new JComboBox();
choices.addItem("Choose");
choices.addItem("Submit Own");
type = new JPanel();
type.add(textarea);
choices.setEditable(false);
choices.setSelectedIndex(0);
frame.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 400);
```

---

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
frame.setContentPane(p);
```

---

```
frame.getContentPane().add(type);
frame.getContentPane().add(choices);
frame.getContentPane().add(voteconfirm);
frame.getContentPane().add(chooser);
frame.getContentPane().add(textarea);
frame.getContentPane().add(password);
frame.getContentPane().add(submit);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

However you need to further learn about LayoutManagers. Take a look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Also check miglayout.net

Answer (score 2):

You need to add all the items to the JPanel **type**, and then add the JPanel component to the JFrame; here is an example

```
  
        frame = new JFrame("Votinator 3000");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        voteconfirm = new JLabel("");
        textarea = new JTextField(1);
        submit = new JButton("Submit Vote!");
        chooser = new JList(items);
        password = new JPasswordField(1);
        password.setVisible(true);
        choices = new JComboBox();
        choices.addItem("Choose");
        choices.addItem("Submit Own");
        type = new JPanel();
        type.add(textarea);
        choices.setEditable(false);
        choices.setSelectedIndex(0);
        frame.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 400);
        frame.add(type);
        type.add(choices);
        type.add(voteconfirm);
        type.add(chooser);
        type.add(textarea);
        type.add(password);
        type.add(submit);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

That should simply work.

Comment: You might want to add that JPanel uses FlowLayout by default. If the OP wants to use a different layout in the `type` panel, they can simply call `type.setLayout()` to change it.